# Casimir Effect and polarization of photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons

I have read Casimir's derivation of the Casimir fore between 2 parallel plates and have been told that in reality, the Casimir force should be twice as large due to the 2 polarization states of photons. I don't understand how/why the 2 polarization states affects the force. Could anyone kindly explain?

Comment: [Casimir effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_Effect) appears because the energy is different between inside and outside 2 parallel plates. And the two polarizations make the difference double. It may be a simple explanation.